# Type AxAXISMEDIACONTROLLib.AxAxisMediaControl is not defined

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms

Me han pasado un proyecto en VisualBasic.NET para echarle un vistazo y al abrirlo y tratar de compilarlo me salta el error:

> ```
> Type AxAXISMEDIACONTROLLib.AxAxisMediaControl is not defined
> ```

Me indica que se encuentra en la linea 1 del Designer.vb

Sin embargo voy a dicha linea y no hay ningun error en ella, es mas, el error que indica no parece tener mucho sentido porque en el codigo me reconoce que esta definido ya que puedo hacer F12

```
 Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Dim resources As System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager = New System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(GetType(Form1))
    Me.Button1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button
    Me.NumericUpDown1 = New System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown
    Me.Button2 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button
    Me.Button3 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button
    Me.AxAxisMediaControl1 = New AxAXISMEDIACONTROLLib.AxAxisMediaControl
....
```

al hacer F12 me salen las propiedades y demas...

```
Imports System
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Namespace AxAXISMEDIACONTROLLib
    <AxHost.Clsid("{7458o5c8-d0e1-8927-8586-624c14o10a8d}")> <DefaultEvent("OnError")> <DesignTimeVisible(True)>
    Public Class AxAxisMediaControl
        Inherits AxHost

    Public Sub New()

    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)> <DispId(60)>
    Public Overridable Property AudioConfigURL As String
    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)> <DispId(63)>
    Public Overridable Property AudioFile As String
    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)> <DispId(163)>
    Public Overridable Property AudioOnlyRTPDelay As Integer
    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)> <DispId(61)>
    Public Overridable Property AudioReceiveURL As String
    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)> <DispId(64)>
    Public Overridable Property AudioTransmitMute As Boolean
```

Edit:
Al abrir la pantalla me salen estos dos errores:

```
1.   Hide Call Stack 


at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid& clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid)
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(Guid clsid)
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.set_Site(ISite value)
at System.ComponentModel.Container.Add(IComponent component, String name)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.PerformAdd(IComponent component, String name)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.System.ComponentModel.Design.IDesignerHost.CreateComponent(Type componentType, String name)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeInstance(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Type type, Object[] parameters, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.ComponentCodeDomSerializer.DeserializeInstance(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Type type, Object[] parameters, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, CodeExpression expression)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializer.DeserializeStatementToInstance(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeStatement statement)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Object codeObject)
at System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Object codeObject)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.DeserializeName(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, CodeStatementCollection statements)
```

y

```
2.   Hide Call Stack 

at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid& clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid)
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(Guid clsid)
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32 state)
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.Add(Control value)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ControlCollection.Add(Control value)
at System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner.DesignerControlCollection.Add(Control c)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cual es el namespace de tu proyecto?

Comment: @Pikoh No veo que este en ningun namespace.

Comment: Viendo el nuevo error, me temo que el problema probablemente es que no tienes la dll instalada en el sistema. Intenta [descargarlo](https://www.axis.com/dk/en/support/downloads/axis-media-control) e instalarlo a ver

Comment: Algo no me queda claro si es `vb.net` o `vb6`

Comment: Pues no me habia fijado en los dos tags la verdad,asumí que era vb.net.

Comment: La verdad, a mi me dijeron que era VB6, pero tiene pinta que hay mezcla

Comment: Si voy a ver si me dicen que version es la que estan usando para instalarla yo tb y ver que tal va, os digo algo cuando lo tenga, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: ¿Pero estás queriendo abrir un proyecto que te dijeron es `vb6` con Studio? ¿Es esto posible?

Comment: @AgustinM. Si, lo abro y el resto de proyectos me los compila bien, este me falla, pero si que se puede.

Comment: Lo siento pero no. Un proyecto vb6 no puede compilarse con Visual Studio @AgustinM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente he conseguido resolver el problema.
Resulta que el error que muestra Visual Studio no es para nada descriptivo y en mi caso el problema era que el Target Framework de uno de los proyectos era el 2.0 cuando hacia referencia a una .dll que estaba compilada en 4.0
Gracias a todos por la ayuda.

Comment: En horabuena por haber encontrado tu respuesta sin embargo Vote negativa tu respuesta ya que creo conveniente que debes modificar tu pregunta especificando cosas como si el error corresponde a vb6 o a vb.net, y darle una mejora al formato. Recuerda que alguien puede encontrar esta pregunta porque le sucede el mismo problema y cuanto más descriptiva sea la relación pregunta-respuesta más valoración tendrá la misma

Comment: Ya he modificado la pregunta, pero no se como formatear la respuesta ya que simplemente se trataba de un error en el Framwork.